# What's a displacement in consumer space? - p 146, Mark Shepherd

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Consumption becomes an aesthetic
>   experience; space and consumption are merged in the special practice producing
>   spaces of consumption. The visual qualities of the arcade architecture enable a
>   spatialization of the goods, **a displacement** and spatial distribution in consumer space.
>   Therefore, the arcade is one of the fi rst distinct urban spaces; spaces of production are
>   characterized by rural aesthetics and ethics emphasizing accumulation, the physical
>   transformation of nature.

Which definition of [displacement](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/displacement) applies? I guess Definition 1, but the passage doesn't say what's being moved? Please explain the steps or thought processes; I’d like to resolve by myself in the future?

Source: 40% down para 1, [p 146](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q&f=false), *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text describes a consumer, also known as a visitor, of an arcade. A room that hosts an arcade is the same as an other large room. Picture the room before any machines are added. The room is only one "space of consumption," or area in which the consumer may use the product. This is the "consumer space."

Now consider just one machine and forget about the room for now. The visual qualities of the machine-the lights, sounds, shape, etc.- form a "space of consumption." When using this one arcade machine, you enter the visually designed "consumer space."

Return your imagining to the initial room, but now fill it with different machines. These machines are distributed throughout the space of the room. In other words, they have "spatial distribution in consumer space," and "spatialization of the goods." In this situation "the goods" refers to the arcade machines.

Each of these individual consumer spaces formed by each machine **displaces** the consumer space of the main room. This use of "displacement" is defined by definition number 1 in your link. The consumer space of the main room is "moved out" and the consumer space of the machine takes its place.

You mention that you wish to resolve a question by yourself in the future. Notice that the concept of "consumer space" in the given text is very abstract. When dealing with abstract concepts, try to imagine the scene in parts, as I have explained above. Strip away your mental scene to its most basic (the empty room described above), then add on details slowly to understand.

EDIT: I noticed that the passage is, in fact, talking about arcade architecture, not arcade machines. My answer still works as an analogy. It is easier to visualize machines than arches anyway.

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your detail. How did you determine and perceive this extremely abstract passage, so well and explain it so readably?!? You must be an expert! How I wish I possess your expertise and wisdom, especially for my test.

Comment: I'm not an expert, just a logophile. I practiced reading difficult passages and thinking critically at school. I would strongly recommend a tutor. As an ELL studying for law, you have a lot of difficult study ahead. Good luck!